# difference between #coding=utf-8 and #coding=gbk

Tags: python, unicode, encode

If there is chinese in .py document , it needs to add #coding=utf-8 and #coding=gbk. But what is the difference between #coding=utf-8 and #coding=gbk in python?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GBK_(character_encoding)

Comment: also read https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ and https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/

Answer (score 1):

The coding comment declares the encoding of the source file itself. If you save the source file in UTF-8 encoding, use `#coding=utf8`. If you save the source file in GBK encoding, use `#coding=gbk`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Unicode characters *in your source code,* you promise that they will be encoded with the encoding you specify in the `# coding` line.

E.g. character `万` will be encoded completely differently in UTF-8 and GBK.

ASCII characters will be encoded the same as ASCII in either case.

Comment: "...they will be encoded with the encoding you specify in the # coding line."  No, they will be encoded in the encoding used to save the file.  The `#coding` line doesn't control the encoding, it just declares the encoding of the source file.  It could declare it *incorrectly*.

Comment: ^ Good point! They will be _expected_ to be encoded according to the comment, and so interpreted, but you need first to actually save the file in this encoding.